# Wordpress mod_rewrite

Tags: xml, wordpress, mod-rewrite, directory

Think I read a bazillion articles over the past couple of days and yet I can still find out how to get mod-rewrites to work how I want.  If you could help I would be forever grateful..

I have a wordpress site, a category called cars, so using the Wordpress Permalinks it generates http://mysite.local/cars/ when I browse into that category.  OK so far?

I want to add a single post, lets call it car, so I can browse to http://mysite.local/cars/car/ and it displays my post.

But what I want to do is rewrite a list of manufacturers and append it to /cars/ but display http://mysite.local/cars/car/

So for example:

- http://mysite.local/cars/dodge/ == http://mysite.local/cars/car/
- http://mysite.local/cars/ford/ == http://mysite.local/cars/car/
- http://mysite.local/cars/bmw/ == http://mysite.local/cars/car/

The manufacturers are stored in an xml file which is changing, but I can deal with that bit later right?

Any suggestions, changes in approach gladly received.

Stu

The Wordpress .htaccess file looks like this for reference:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I am so frustrated with this I'm about to create a script to physically create the directory structure I want.. which of course I dont want to do

Comment: Is my approach wrong? I always seem to find the questions that no one seems to want to answer! grrrrrrr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't go on like this.

If you do a rewrite, you need to conserve the variable. Or else the server won't be able to know if you ask `http://mysite.local/cars/car/`for dodge, ford or anything else.

What can be done is :

```
RewriteRule ^cars/car/(.*)$ cars/car.php?model=$1 [L]
```

So that you just have one page called `car.php` that handle your requests via a `model` parameter. But I don't think it will suit you, since it's a reversal of the `clean URL` paradigm.

Maybe you can use

```
RewriteRule ^cars/car/(.*)$ cars/car/ [E=MODEL:$1]
```

But the page addressed by `cars/car/` will have to fetch the model value from the environments variables.